# Why the strtok function ignores two tokens one after the other

Tags: arrays, c, string, strtok

I have a code that split my char str[] to tokens:

```
void my_function(char str[])
{   
    int i = 0;
    char *p = strtok(str, "/");
    char *rows[SIZE] = { NULL };

        while(p==NULL)
        {
            rows[i++] = p;
            p = strtok(NULL, "/");
        }
}
```

There is a problem with 2 tokens('/') one after other to save the orders of tokens

**example: "abc/a//bb"**

(SIZE=4)

rows=['abc','a','bb',null]

and I want that the result will be:

rows=['abc','a',null,'bb'] (save the orders of tokens)

How can I over this problem?

Comment: `strtok` only returns `NULL` if no more tokens are found. If there are multiple delimiters in row it will "squash" them together. From the `man` page: *The start of the
       next token is determined by scanning forward for the **next
       nondelimiter** byte in str*

Comment: @HELO Use functions strspn and strcspn. Or if the delimiter is only one character '/' then you can use strchr and substitute the found character '/' for '\0'

Comment: It's designed this way so it can be used for parsing whitespace-separated words and allow any number of spaces. Or words separated by spaces and punctuation, it skips over all of them.

Comment: @HELO By the way how many sub-strings will be in these strings "S/" and "/S" where 'S' is a space?

Comment: @VladfromMoscow 2

Comment: @HELO Why does the first string contain two sub-strings?! Is not it contain only one string because after the found delimiter there is only the terminating zero?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that is `strtok()`'s behavior. The tokens passed to `strtok()` are usually separated by some kind of whitespace, and that's the user's expectation when the separator is whitespace.

To overcome, implement your own tokenizer.

```
char *tokenize(char *s, char t, char **ctx)
{
    if (s) *ctx = s;
    if (!*ctx) return NULL;
    s = *ctx;
    if (!*s) return NULL;
    while (**ctx) {
       if (**ctx == t) {
           **ctx = 0;
           ++*ctx;
           return NULL;
       }
       ++*ctx;
    }
    return s;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`strtok` gives you tokens separated by strings of 1 or more delimiter characters, so by definition, you can't get empty tokens.  If you want tokens separated by single character delimiters, use `strsep` instead.  Unofrtunately, that is only available on BSD and Linux systems, but is easy enough to write yourself:

```
char *strsep(char **stringp, const char *delim) {
    char *rv = *stringp;
    if (rv) {
        *stringp += strcspn(rv, delim);
        if (**stringp)
            *(*stringp)++ = '\0';
        else
            *stringp = NULL;
    }
    return rv;
}
```